# how do I inherit launcher icons from a library project in android?

Tags: android, android-launcher, library-project

I have several apps dependent on a library project. I wish them all to use the same launcher icons. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be getting inherited?

I'm getting the generic icon for android...

Comment: How are you trying to "inherit" them? There's no inheritance for that, AFAIK. You CAN, however, access the resources of the other project and use them in the other project's manifest.

Comment: I was told to add this to my application manifest xmlns:base="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/my.package.base"

Comment: and that mysteriously works...

Comment: Please, add it as answer, accept it and then the question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: my App does not select the launcher icon on the library project but uses the default Android icon.

As suggested in comments, I inserted a line in the manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mylib="schemas.android.com/apk/res/mylib.libpackage.libbase 
    package="myapp.apppackage.appbase"
    android:versionCode="100"
    android:versionName="2.1.0" >
```

The line is:

```
xmlns:base="schemas.android.com/apk/res/mylib.libpackage.libbase
```

the name space `mylib.libpackage.libbase` is the package name defined in the library manifes.xml.

to reference the launcher icon use

```
android:icon="@mylib:drawable/ic_launcher"
```

**But.. this not works for me!**

Simply I found I need to use the standard approach:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

and **deleted the ic_launcher resource form all libraries** used in my project (except for the library used as icon resource).